# how to access outer class properties inside the inner classes?

Tags: python, inner-classes

```
class Remote:
aa=7
def __init__(self):
    self.name="Lenovo"
    self.b=self.Battery()
    print("this is outer",self.b.t)
class Battery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="Hp"
        self.t="df"
        self.c=self.Cover()
    class Cover:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name="Arplastic"
        
c1=Remote()
```

I knew today about inner class but i don't know how to i access properties and methods of     outer class into inner class please let me know anyone.

Comment: It's very rarely useful to nest classes like this. There's no guarantee for a given instance of the inner classes that the outer class has even been instantiated.

Comment: An "inner" class isn't granted any special scoping to the enclosing class. A ```Cover``` instance has to interact with a ```Battery``` instance the same way as any other object.

Answer (score 1):

Change the constructor(s) of the inner class(es) to accept a `parent` argument and have the creating instance pass itself to it:

```
class Remote:
    aa=7
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="Lenovo"
        self.b=self.Battery(self)
        print("this is outer",self.b.t)
    class Battery:
        def __init__(self,parent):
            self.name="Hp"
            self.t="df"
            self.c=self.Cover(self)
            self.parent=parent
        class Cover:
            def __init__(self,parent):
                self.name="Arplastic"
                self.parent=parent

c1=Remote()
print(c1.b.c.parent.parent.name) # prints 'Lenovo'
```

Comment: thank you sir this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make a metaclass that automatically creates `self.parent` attributes for nested classes. Note that there is a trade-off between readability and boilerplate here - many programmers would rather you just manually pass parents as arguments and add them to `__init__` methods. This is more fun though, and there is something to be said for having less cluttered code.

Here is the code:

```
import inspect


def inner_class(cls):
    cls.__is_inner_class__ = True
    return cls


class NestedClass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs, parent=None):
        attrs = dict(attrs.items())
        super_getattribute = attrs.get('__getattribute__', object.__getattribute__)
        inner_class_cache = {}

        def __getattribute__(self, attr):
            val = super_getattribute(self, attr)
            if inspect.isclass(val) and getattr(val, '__is_inner_class__', False):
                if (self, val) not in inner_class_cache:
                    inner_class_cache[self, val] = NestedClass(val.__name__, val.__bases__, val.__dict__, parent=self)

                return inner_class_cache[self, val]
            else:
                return val

        attrs['__getattribute__'] = __getattribute__
        attrs['parent'] = parent

        return type(name, bases, attrs)


class Remote(metaclass=NestedClass):
    aa = 7

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Lenovo"
        self.b = self.Battery()
        print("this is outer", self.b.t)

    @inner_class
    class Battery:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "Hp"
            self.t = "df"
            self.c = self.Cover()

        @inner_class
        class Cover:
            def __init__(self):
                self.name = "Arplastic"
                print(f'{self.parent=}, {self.parent.parent=}')


c1 = Remote()
print(f'{c1.b.c.parent.parent is c1=}')
print(f'{isinstance(c1.b, c1.Battery)=}')
```

Output:

```
self.parent=<__main__.Battery object at 0x7f11e74936a0>, self.parent.parent=<__main__.Remote object at 0x7f11e7493730>
this is outer df
c1.b.c.parent.parent is c1=True
isinstance(c1.b, c1.Battery)=True
```

The way this works is by storing the `parent` as a class attribute (which is `None` by default), and replacing the `__getattribute__` method so that all inner classes are replaced with `NestedClass`es with the `parent` attribute correctly filled in.

The `inner_class` decorator is used to mark a class as an inner class by setting the `__is_inner_class__` attribute.

```
def inner_class(cls):
    cls.__is_inner_class__ = True
    return cls
```

This is not strictly necessary if all attributes that are classes should be treated as inner classes, but it's good practice to do something like this to prevent `Bar.foo` being treated as an inner class in this example:

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar(metaclass=NestedClass):
    foo = Foo
```

All the `NestedClass` metaclass does is take the description of the class and modify it, adding the `parent` attribute:

```
class NestedClass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs, parent=None):
        attrs = dict(attrs.items())
        
        ...

        attrs['parent'] = parent

        return type(name, bases, attrs)
```

...and modifying the `__getattribute__` method. The `__getattribute__` method is a special method that gets called every time an attribute is accessed. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "baz"
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return 1

foo = Foo()
# these assert statements pass because even though `foo.bar` is set to "baz" and `foo.remote` doesn't exist, accessing either of them is the same as calling `Foo.__getattribute(foo, ...)`
assert foo.bar == 1
assert foo.remote == 1
```

So, by modifying the `__getattribute__` method, you can make accessing `self.Battery` return a class that has its `parent` attribute equal to `self`, and also make it into a nested class:

```
class NestedClass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs, parent=None):
        attrs = dict(attrs.items())
        # get the previous __getattribute__ in case it was not the default one
        super_getattribute = attrs.get('__getattribute__', object.__getattribute__)
        inner_class_cache = {}

        def __getattribute__(self, attr):
            # get the attribute
            val = super_getattribute(self, attr)
            if inspect.isclass(val) and getattr(val, '__is_inner_class__', False):
                # if it is an inner class, then make a new version of it using the NestedClass metaclass, setting the parent attribute
                if (self, val) not in inner_class_cache:
                    inner_class_cache[self, val] = NestedClass(val.__name__, val.__bases__, val.__dict__, parent=self)

                return inner_class_cache[self, val]
            else:
                return val

        attrs['__getattribute__'] = __getattribute__
        attrs['parent'] = parent

        return type(name, bases, attrs)
```

Note that a cache is used to ensure that `self.Battery` will always return the same object every time rather than re-making the class every time it is called. This ensures that checks like `isinstance(c1.b, c1.Battery)` work correctly, since otherwise `c1.Battery` would return a different object to the one used to create `c1.b`, causing this to return `False`, when it should return `True`.

And that's it! You can now enjoy nested classes without boilerplate!